# Simplify c# if/else statement with different List<>

Tags: c#, if-statement

Is there any way to simplify the following code? 
supportList is an object which is getting from constructor:

```
 public void FillCollection(object supportList)
```

Code here:

```
if (supportList is List<Bank>)
{
    foreach (var temp in supportList as List<Bank>)
    {
        //code here
    }
}
else if (supportList is List<Currency>)
{
    foreach (var temp in supportList as List<Currency>)
    {
        //code here
    }
}
else if (supportList is List<Amount>)
{
    foreach (var temp in supportList as List<Amount>)
    {
        //code here
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1:** All foreach parts do the same code like

```
foreach (var temp in supportList as List<Bank>)
{
    string yesno;
    if (temp.Id == CurrentId)
    {
        yesno = "" + yes;
    }
    else
    {
        yesno = "" + no;
    }

    CollectionSupport.Add(new SupportModel { Id = temp.Id, Name = temp.Name, 
    Code = temp.Code, YesNo = "" + yesno });
}
```

Comment: Is your //code here part same for all three statement blocks ?

Comment: Yes. You simplify this by not doing this. What you *should* do, we can't tell. Maybe [edit] and describe what your goals are here?

Comment: @GiladGreen dont want to overload methods)

Comment: @MichalHainc didn't use generic lists, may you provide me good example?

Comment: Show a example of what `//code here` would do. Also, do all 3 of those classes inerit a common base class or a interface?

Comment: Why are you concatenating an empty string with a value instead of just assigning the value? i.e. this: `yesno = "" + no;` should just be this: `yesno = no;`, shouldn't it? (or, even better, your `YesNo` property should be a `bool` instead of a `string`, and have a better name, like `IsCurrent`)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a duck-typing problem: where your `Bank`, `Currency`, and `Amount` types have the same members (`Id`, `Name`, and `Code`) but share no common hierarchy.

A solution is to create a new `interface` (I called it `ICurrencyBankOrAmount`) which declares these members, then add the interface to your `Bank`, `Currency`, and `Amount` model classes, then you can have a single loop body - I've converted it to a Linq expression for you below:

```
public void FillCollection<TItem>(List<TItem> supportList)
    where TITem : ICurrencyBankOrAmount
{

    this.CollectionSupport.AddRange(
        supportList
            .Select( item => new SupportModel()
            {
                Id = item.Id,
                Name = item.Name,
                Code = item.Code,
                YesNo = item.Id == this.CurrentId ? "yes" : "no"
            } )
    )
}
```

If you cannot modify those classes, you can use the Adapter Pattern.

Comment: Pretty much this, yeah. The method doesn't actually need to be generic here though.

Comment: @hvd I understand making it generic avoids vtable calls on interface methods - but the performance improvement would be negligible.

Comment: @Dai That's mainly beneficial when `TItem` might be a value type, as I understand it, but you're right, that can sometimes be a good reason for creating a generic method even if technically a non-generic method would work too.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your classes implement a common interface.

```
public interface ISomeDescriptiveNameHere {
  public string Id { get; }
  public string Name { get; }
  public string Code { get; }
}
```

Then you can write

```
public void FillCollection(IReadOnlyList<ISomeDescriptiveNameHere> supportList) {
    foreach (var temp in supportList) {
       string yesno;
       if (temp.Id == CurrentId) {
           yesno = "" + yes;
       } else {
           yesno = "" + no;
       }
       CollectionSupport.Add(new SupportModel { Id = temp.Id, Name = temp.Name, Code = temp.Code, YesNo = "" + yesno });
   }
}
```

This relies on the fact that `List<T>` implements `IReadOnlyList<T>`, and `IReadOnlyList<T>` is covariant in `T`, meaning it can be transparently passed as `IReadOnlyList<U>` where `U` is any base class or implemented interface of `T`.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but the Dai have been first with the same example including linq.